# primefaces notificationbar autohide

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a notificationBar and a commandButton to show it. It works fine, but I need the notificationBar hide itself without the need to click a commandButton to hide it.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: On which event it should be hidden or just after some time?

Comment: Yes, it could be like that!! Or it could be a cross inside the notificationBar to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what you have to do to close the notificationbar is the following is to call `notificationWidget.hide()` when you specified `widgetVar="notificationWidget"` as a attribute of the notificationbar.

If you would like to have a cross inside the bar to close it, you have to put a `commandButton` or just a button inside the notificationbar and which calls `notificationWidget.hide()` on click.

To close the notificationbar after some fixed time you have to register a timer when the notificationbar shows. I.e. `setTimeout(notificationWidget.hide, 3000)` to close it after 3 seconds.

If you know more exactly what you want to do give some more information or some code, so that i can give you some more concrete answer.

Comment: commandbutton inside notificationbar is fine for me, but can you please tell me how can I set setTimeout function code? <h:form>
 <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin: 0px auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <p:column>
   <p:notificationBar position="top" widgetVar="topBar" effect="slide">
    <h:outputText value="2013 Company | Todos os direitos reservados"/>
   </p:notificationBar>
   <p:commandButton value="Termos e Condições" onclick="topBar.show()" type="button" styleClass="buttonTermsConditions" />
  </p:column>
 </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>

Comment: One simple option would be to set the timer in the onclick of the commandButton after `topBar.show()`. I.e. `onclick="topBar.show();setTimeout(topBar.hide,3000);"`.

Comment: I put commandButton to hide inside notificationBar and also change onclick to close automatically like you said. Thank you so much. onclick="topBar.show();setTimeout('topBar.hide()',6000);"